# how to use django restframework as a backend for mobile apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to built an "API". Using django restframework. API has to support multiple platforms like mobile apps, webapps.
API will be used as a backend which will store all information. But my problem is how do I access users information using API. I mean normally django has user model. And we access user related stuff using request.user. But how do I access request.user information using API. Please pardon me for asking such question. But as I am new to developing API for Mobile apps. I am facing difficulty.

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to think about it, is that Django Rest Framework will (normally) return or process JSON data, rather than an HTML page / HTML form data.

Your models stay the same.

If you use Django's ModelForms then DRF's ModelSerialzers are very similar in use.

Likewise, using Django's class based generic views, are very similar to DRF's  generic views are very similar - except rather than processing POST data from an HTML forms, they will receive JSON data. The generic views cover the same things - create  via POST, update via PUT, delete via DELETE.

Like I say the main difference is that you will be dealing with JSON in place of HTML.

(You could easily use bog standard Django views without the rest-framework and return or process JSON. DRF takes a fair bit of the boilerplate code out of the process).

Comment: When app server and rest-framework server are same. It means we can access user information for every HTTP request but when API server is different then how to access user information for every request.

Comment: django-rest-framework is an addition to your application, not separate. You will still need to create models and users. You can server HTML via normal Django views, or JSON via the REST framework views.  If you are putting them on different servers, you are creating two separate apps. Syncronising them will be a pain.